# How can I convert a character code to a string character in Lua?

Tags: string, lua

How can I convert a character code to a string character in Lua?

E.g.

```
d = 48
-- this is what I want
str_d = "0"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for [`string.char`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-string.char):

> ```
> string.char (···)
> ```
>
> Receives zero or more integers. Returns a string with length equal to the number of arguments, in which each character has the internal numerical code equal to its corresponding argument.
>
> Note that numerical codes are not necessarily portable across platforms.

For your example:

```
local d = 48
local str_d = string.char(d) -- str_d == "0"
```

Answer (score 2):

For ASCII characters, you can use `string.char`.

For UTF-8 strings, you can use [`utf8.char`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-utf8.char)(introduced in Lua 5.3) to get a character from its code point.

```
print(utf8.char(48))    -- 0
print(utf8.char(29790)) -- 瑞
```